# SDL: Timers and WaitEvent

Tags: c, sdl

So, the main loop of my game is based on a SDL_WaitEvent type, where it waits for the user to enter new letters while trying to discover a random word. My game need this to work properly but it looks like SDL_WaitEvent stays idle until user press something. The problem is I need my timer to continuosly refresh in order for the player to keep track of it, but when the game reaches the event loop, my timer stays idle and I am not able to find a away to keep it refreshing, any tips would be very appreciated.

Summarizing:

Timer starts: 59 (seconds)
.
.
.

It only will refresh and show the time elapsed when and IF I press something.

Comment: run two threads perhaps?

Comment: Is it that trivial running another thread? Google searches make it sound more of a problem than it's worth.

Comment: Does it have to be `SDL_WaitEvent`? What's wrong with using the more common `SDL_PollEvent` and switching on the event type essentially doing nothing unless you get a keyboard event. Also would help if you should the code.

Answer (score 4):

[`SDL_AddTimer()` with a callback that uses `SDL_PushEvent()` to post a user message to the event queue](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer#Code_Examples):

```
/* Start the timer; the callback below will be executed after the delay */

Uint32 delay = (33 / 10) * 10;  /* To round it down to the nearest 10 ms */
SDL_TimerID my_timer_id = SDL_AddTimer(delay, my_callbackfunc, my_callback_param);

...

Uint32 my_callbackfunc(Uint32 interval, void *param)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_UserEvent userevent;

    /* In this example, our callback pushes an SDL_USEREVENT event
    into the queue, and causes our callback to be called again at the
    same interval: */

    userevent.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
    userevent.code = 0;
    userevent.data1 = NULL;
    userevent.data2 = NULL;

    event.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
    event.user = userevent;

    SDL_PushEvent(&event);
    return(interval);
}
```